# Taylor series representation

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

I don't understand how the taylor series representation follows the derivative requirements for $f(x)$. If I plug in $n=2$ into the taylor polynomial, I don't get $0$ for this term but I should because $f^n(2)$ is zero for all even $n$'s so the whole expression should be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They’ve used the fact that it’s 0 for even n to just remove those from the sum so they sum over n in the format 2n+1 which gives us only the odd terms